# How to plot each year as a line with months on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I have a question, I have the following dataframe containing multiple years and months with an total sum:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Bedrag': [210406.49, 191369.87, 118458.65, 81682.95, 90571.61, 196374.53, 223619.85, 144773.64, 240221.67, 110666.73, 108633.49, 194808.85, 103302.85, 186419.17, 96297.53, 81404.79, 94874.21, 209520.46, 270694.15, 107448.21, 188290.77, 163761.78, 168799.28, 190937.74, 127930.28, 262299.96, 48658.0, 48027.57, 220501.67, 234570.63, 89188.45, 233270.46, 179647.23, 272358.86],
        'Jaar': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
        'maand': ['April', 'August', 'December', 'February', 'January', 'July', 'June', 'March', 'May', 'November', 'October', 'September', 'April', 'August', 'December', 'February', 'January', 'July', 'June', 'March', 'May', 'November', 'October', 'September', 'April', 'August', 'February', 'January', 'July', 'June', 'March', 'May', 'October', 'September']}

correct_omzet = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(correct_omzet.head())

      Bedrag  Jaar     maand
0  210406.49  2019     April
1  191369.87  2019    August
2  118458.65  2019  December
3   81682.95  2019  February
4   90571.61  2019   January
```

Now I would like to plot this with seaborn in a line plot to see a season sales pattern. But when I try to plot as below, the outcome only shows the 12 months.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25,6))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.lineplot(data=correct_omzet, x="maand", y="Bedrag", ci=None, color="green", marker='o')
```

[image: Line plot 2019]

I've also tried to plot it without seaborn:

```
correct_omzet.plot.line(x='maand', rot=90, y='Bedrag', title='Omzetpatroon 2019 - 2021', colormap='Spectral', figsize=(20,8))
plt.minorticks_on()
```

[image: plot without seaborn]

But then I can't figure out to get all the months as x-axis titles.

Answer (score 4):

- The clearest way to make seasonal observations is to plot each year as a separate line, with the x-axis as the months
- Set the month column as ordered categorical with [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), which will ensure the months are plotted in order. The built-in [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) package is used for the ordered `month_name` list, or create a list manually.
- Use the figure-level [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with `kind='line'` to plot the data and separate `'Jaar'` with the `hue=` parameter.

  - The figure-level plot is used because it has `height` and `aspect` for sizing, removing the need to create `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 10))`. Otherwise use the axes-level [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).
- Also see [Weather Visualization for Portland, OR: 1940 - 2020](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/projects/Portland_Weather/Portland_Weather.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from calendar import month_name as mn

# month list
months = mn[1:]

# convert the column to categorical and ordered
correct_omzet.maand = pd.Categorical(correct_omzet.maand, categories=months, ordered=True)

# plot the data
p = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=correct_omzet, x='maand', y='Bedrag', hue='Jaar', aspect=2.5, marker='o')
```

[image]