# How to order the tick labels on a discrete axis (0 indexed like a bar plot)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe with this data and want to plot it with a bar graph with x-axis labels being months

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Birthday': ['1900-01-31', '1900-02-28', '1900-03-31', '1900-04-30', '1900-05-31', '1900-06-30', '1900-07-31', '1900-08-31', '1900-09-30', '1900-10-31', '1900-11-30', '1900-12-31'],
        'Players': [32, 25, 27, 19, 27, 18, 18, 21, 23, 21, 26, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  Birthday Players
1900-01-31      32
1900-02-28      25
1900-03-31      27
1900-04-30      19
1900-05-31      27
1900-06-30      18
1900-07-31      18
1900-08-31      21
1900-09-30      23
1900-10-31      21
1900-11-30      26
1900-12-31      23
```

This is what I have

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.bar(month_df.index, month_df.Players, color = 'maroon', width=10)
```

but the result is this with the label starting from Feb instead of Jan

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Bar plot x-axis tick locations are 0 indexed, not datetimes
- **This solution applies to any plot with a discrete axis (e.g. bar, hist, heat, etc.)**.
- Similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70049587/7758804), the easiest solution follows:

  - Skip to step 3 if the `str` column already exists

  1. Convert the `'Birthday'` column to a `datetime dtype` with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
  2. Extract the abbreviated month name to a separate column
  3. Order the column with [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html). The build-in [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module is used to supply an ordered list of abbreviated month names, or the list can be typed manually
  4. Plot the dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from calendar import month_abbr as ma  # ordered abbreviated month names

# convert the Birthday column to a datetime and extract only the date component
df.Birthday = pd.to_datetime(df.Birthday)

# create a month column
df['month'] = df.Birthday.dt.strftime('%b')

# convert the column to categorical and ordered
df.month = pd.Categorical(df.month, categories=ma[1:], ordered=True)

# plot the dataframe
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='month', y='Players', figsize=(12, 7), rot=0, legend=False)
```

[image]

- If there are many repeated months, where the data must be aggregated, then combine the data using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate some function like `.mean()` or `.sum()`

```py
dfg = df.groupby('month').Players.sum()

ax = dfg.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(12, 7), rot=0, legend=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically, matplotlib.bar does not do a very good job with datetimes for various reasons. It's easy to manually set your x tick locations and labels as below. This a [fixed formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) convenience wrapper function, but it lets you take control quite easily.

```
#generate data
data = pd.Series({
    '1900-01-31' : 32,    '1900-02-28' : 25,    '1900-03-31' : 27,
    '1900-04-30' : 19,    '1900-05-31' : 27,    '1900-06-30' : 18,
    '1900-07-31' : 18,    '1900-08-31' : 21,    '1900-09-30' : 23,
    '1900-10-31' : 21,    '1900-11-30' : 26,    '1900-12-31' : 23,
    })

#make plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))
ax.bar(range(len(data)), data, color = 'maroon', width=0.5, zorder=3)

#ax.set_xticks uses a fixed locator
ax.set_xticks(range(len(data)))
#ax.set_xticklables uses a fixed formatter
ax.set_xticklabels(pd.to_datetime(data.index).strftime('%b'))

#format plot a little bit
ax.spines[['top','right']].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, bottom=False, labelsize=13)
ax.grid(axis='y', color='gray', dashes=(8,3), alpha=0.5)
```

[image: fixed x datetime tick labels in matplotlib bar chart]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with matplotlib.dates but because you are using pandas there are simple ways doing what you need using pandas.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# data
data = {'Birthday': ['1900-01-31', '1900-02-28', '1900-03-31', '1900-04-30', '1900-05-31', '1900-06-30', '1900-07-31', '1900-08-31', '1900-09-30', '1900-10-31', '1900-11-30', '1900-12-31'],
        'Players': [32, 25, 27, 19, 27, 18, 18, 21, 23, 21, 26, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert column to datetime
df["Birthday"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Birthday"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

# groupby month and plot bar plot
df.groupby(df["Birthday"].dt.month).sum().plot(kind="bar", color = "maroon")

# set plot properties
plt.xlabel("Birthday Month")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.xticks(ticks = range(0,12) ,labels = calendar.month_name[1:])

# show plot
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output image]