# How can I turn this into multiple line plots?

Tags: seaborn, line-plot

I assigned the x - axis as the number of days, 365, and my response variable for y-axis. However, upon using seaborn, it sets my x-axis as the whole number of rows I have.
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOaMl.png)

`sns.lineplot(x="DATE", y="TMEAN", data=TS, hue="YEAR", style="YEAR") plt.show`
[Lineplot Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myKXP.jpg)
I tried to use pivot and melt, but to no avail.

Comment: Dear pyhsics_python, it would be nice if you could include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - this way we can give you more concrete and detailed feedback. The plotting function does what you told it to do! You asked it to take the "DATE" on the x-axis. Your data includes 3285 (9 years with 365 days each - or 364 for the leap years) points that are being plotted. The "hue" only colors the years differently and the "style" parameter applies different line styles to each year.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70016547/7758804

Comment: I will take note on that @Baradrist , I am still quite learning how to ask and post here on stackoverflow. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to fix your problem is to use the "day of the year" instead of the column "DATE". You can extract that as a separate column from the date like in this example:

```
data = {'DATE': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', end='2021-12-31'),
        'YEAR': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', end='2021-12-31').year,
        'DAY': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', end='2021-12-31').dayofyear,
        'TMEAN': your_temp_data}

TS = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
sns.lineplot(data=TS, x='DAY', y='TMEAN', hue="YEAR")
plt.show()
```

Here, the "dayofyear" gives you your x-axis (being each day without the information of which year the temperature belongs to) and the coloring hue visualizes the year.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I tried adding a column for day of year and it works. But my graph kind of not pleasing, so I guess I will stick with this.